# Java images not appearing in jar aplication

Tags: java, image

As in the title, my images do not show up in my jar application. When I run my project, everything is alright. But when I export it, and try to run it, my images do not load in.

Fragment from my code :

```
public static BufferedImage Player, Chest , Crate, FinishFlag, Grass, TabDown, TabUp, TabLeft, TabRight, Dirt;
```

```
    public static void init() {

        SpriteSheet sheet = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/Player_idle.png"));
        Player = sheet.crop(0, 0,width,height);
        Chest = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/chest.png");
        Crate = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/crate.png");
        FinishFlag= ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/finish_flag.png");
        Grass = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/gras.png");
        TabDown = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/tab_down.png");
        TabUp = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/tab_up.png");
        TabLeft = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/tab_left.png");
        TabRight = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/tab_right.png");
        Dirt = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/dirt.png");
    }
```

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My [jar file screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkwHH.png)

Comment: Where are your images stored? Is the directory they're stored in marked as a source or resource directory?

Comment: In a resource directory.

Comment: An exception is probably being thrown. Launch the JAR via a command prompt.